# Is it well defined behaviour to save a destructor adress of an object and call it later?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management

I am currently working on a Stack Allocator, written in C++. It shall be possible to get objects from this Stack Allocator via a template method. These objects should be destructed once another deallocation method is called. When experimenting with different approaches to achieve the invocation of the destructor I stumbled across the following:

```
auto destructor = someObject->~SomeClass;
destructor();
```

The destructor seems to be acctually called, however this looks kind of strange to me. I have the following questions:

1. Is this well-defined behavior?
2. What's the type of a destructor (with what could I replace the auto keyword)?
3. Could I save all destructor addresses of several objects of different types in a list and invoke them later?

Comment: It's definitely not safe.  What happens if you accidentally call the destructor twice?

Comment: Yes I know that it's dangerous. I would work around the dangers if it is well-defined by removing the adresses once they are called.

Comment: What compiler allows this?  Both g++ and clang++ complain when I tried it.

Comment: VS2015 allows this. Not even a warning with /W3

Comment: You might be looking for [`deferred_heap`](https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp). It comes with a free [CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: How are you allocating the memory for the objects in your allocator?

Comment: Calling the destructor doesn't actually free the memory.  When do you free the memory?

Comment: It will get called but it won't know which object to destroy, unless you're doing it from within the class.

Comment: Not well formed see [§\[class.dtor\]/p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.dtor#2): `The address of a destructor shall not be taken`. It is basically undefined behavior, but I would file a bug report, it would good to get a diagnostic.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour More on point is [expr.ref]/4.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I save all destructor addresses of several objects of different
>   types in a list and invoke them later?

yes. Do note that my solution also keeps a pointer to the destructed object, not only the destructor.
you can do a bit of lambda magic to achieve that + a bit of low level help:

```
class GenericDestructor {

private:    
    const void* object;
    void(*destructor)(const void*);

public:

    template<class T>
    GenericDestructor(const T& _object) noexcept :
        object(std::addressof(_object)){

        destructor = [](const void* _object) {
            auto original = static_cast<const T*>(_object);
            original->~T();
        };

    };

    void operator () () noexcept {
        destructor(object);
    }

};
```

storing:

```
std::vector<GenericDestructor> storedDestructors;
auto needsToBeDeleted = new std::string();
storedDestructors.emplace_back(*needsToBeDeleted);
```

destructing all stored objects:

```
for(auto& storedDestructor : storedDestructors) storedDestructor();
```

Comment: Or use this lambda as the second argument to `std::shared_ptr<void*>::shared_ptr(T* ptr, Deleter)`.

Comment: possible. but the OP should consider that this solution has much more overhead to the bonus that now the object si reference counted.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments note, this is Undefined Behavior/compiler extension.

It is possible to do what you want, though:

```
template<typename T>
std::function<void(T*)> defer_dtor()
{
   return [](T* ptr) {ptr->~T();};
}
```

or directly (more like your question, but the unique lambda type cannot be added directly to a list.)

```
auto destructor = [&]{someObject->~SomeClass();};
destructor();
```

Note: this follows your question, and doesn't call `delete ptr`. Whether that's appropriate depends on the context, but presumably if you wanted to wrap `delete ptr` you would just have used `std::shared_ptr`.

[edit]
I missed one tiny bit in your question: "save all destructor addresses of several objects *of different types* in a list".

That's going to be a problem. A design problem, to be precise. How are those types related? If by inheritance, you don't need a list of destructors, but a `virtual` destructor. If the types aren't related, how do you match the objects and the saved destructors? And if you do have the types of all those objects, why don't you just call `->~Type()`  directly?

Comment: it is possible. see my answer. you can convert a lambda to function pointer and that lambda can be a part of a templated function.

Comment: @DavidHaim: That assumes you have not just the object _type_, but the actual object itself available. But in that case, why not bind the object itself into the lambda? Your class looks like a hand-rolled equivalent of `[object]{object->~T();}`.

Comment: performance. capturing context in the lambda prevents it to be casted into a function pointer. it needs to be stored in a `std::function` which probably uses virtual functions + function object is fatter than a single `void(*)(void*)`. by adding a few lines of code, you optimize your allocator greatly. you might shout "premature optimization" but if you already took the time to write stack allocator than it's not premature - you're already optimizing.

Comment: @DavidHaim: As virtual functions are generally implemented as function pointer tables, I consider the two roughly equivalent. And yes, the capture means it can't be casted to a function pointer, but that's exactly because it internalizes state that you keep external (`void* object`). Of course, this fundamental equivalence is due to the fact that we both solve the problem with a layer of indirection. I'm just betting on a better optimization of standard constructs over hand-rolled equivalents.

Comment: I do agree however, that one can adapt the `GenericDesrtuctor` class into using only `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Doesn't look like proof to me. In that case the optimizer can see right through the function pointer and inlines your example. But if you **need** that indirection, e.g. because you're storing a mix of these in a list (as per the question), then the optimizer can't eliminate the indirection.

Comment: I'm not talking about the delete itself , but the deleter. how do you think `std::function` works internally? it uses type-erasure. it also have sbo. so when you destruct a std::function you have to ask if the buffer is small or big, than invoke virtual destructor on the buffer. not to mention that `std::function` is heavier on the memory uage. GenericDestructor is a lean-POD type. you can benchmark both of the destructors with mixed types. see how much time it takes to destroy the stored objects + destroy the deleters themselves. then tell me the standard "has better optimizations".

Comment: I love the standard. I use `std::function` anywhere myself. but I don't blindly think the standard can do a better job everywhere or somehow bestow upon the compiler magical optimization capabilities. If I anyway write my own allocator in speed in mind, why would I care adding a few lines of code that makes everything faster?

Comment: @DavidHaim: The costly CPU operation is an indirect jump. You need to fetch a code pointer from memory, and make an indirect jump to that address. It's this particular operation which stalls the instruction prefetcher and makes the code slow (many nanoseconds). It doesn't matter much whether that pointer is fetched from a vtable or elsewhere.